# How to change Firefox searchbar from google.com to google.com.tw

Tags: firefox

I install Ubuntu 11.04 Chinese version.
But Firefox's title and search bar also in English.

How to change back to Chinese version?

The important thing for me is change search bar to google.com.tw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the search bar:

1. Install the ['Add to Search Bar' add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-to-search-bar/) for Firefox.
2. Go to [www.google.com.tw](http://www.google.com.tw/).
3. Right click on the search field and select "Add to search bar" in the contextual menu.

For the search built in the address bar:

1. Type about:config into the address bar.
2. Search for "keyword.url"
3. Change its value by adding "tw" where "google.com" is written.

Adapted from [DuckDuckGo instructions](http://help.duckduckgo.com/customer/portal/articles/216441).